# changing page sections with links

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am confused what to use changing only the page sections.
I have an image to make my question more clear.

[image]

The about us section has links in the right. Each links i click, the whole section should change. I know it uses javascript or ajax to do it without reloading the page. Is there any other way i could do it sonner? Can bootstrap carousel can be handy?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Single page hide/show section based on current position](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20958030/single-page-hide-show-section-based-on-current-position)

Answer (score 1):

Bootstraps carousel would be hard to alter since its built into the framework, you could use jQuery UI for the tabs and style them or make your own.

I found this pure CSS example and I think this is what you are looking for (credits to Kezz Bracey), this is a fully CSS3 tabs collection, all you would need to do with this example is alter the code to work with your page (ie: her tabs are on top, yours are on the right.)

```
Anyway, here is the link:
```

[Pure CSS3 and HTML5 tabs - Codepen](http://codepen.io/tutsplus/pen/VLeXqy?editors=110)

> P.S: I would have put this as a comment but my rep isn't high enough
>   yet, hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks, This is exactly what i was looking for. Without jquery or js. Its absolutely amazing but i am having a hard time dividing the tabs into different column and the content into another.

Comment: is this not tagging you. :/

Answer (score 0):

You should try giving each section an `id`and relate the `id`'s of the links to them. Now you can use jQuery to scroll to that particular section on click of the link.

```
function scrollToSection(id){
  // Remove "link" from the ID
  id = id.replace("link", "");
  // Scroll
  $('html,body').animate({
    scrollTop: $("#"+id).offset().top},
    'slow');
}

$("#sidebar > ul > li > a").click(function(e) { 
  // Prevent a page reload when a link is pressed
  e.preventDefault(); 
  // Call the scroll function
  scrollToSection($(this).attr("id"));           
});
```

Check out the demo here : https://jsfiddle.net/VPzxG/

**OR**

If you don't want the animation while scrolling to a different section, you can use plain HTML for that.

Check out this demo : https://jsfiddle.net/ywxbLswt/

**OR**

If you want to hide/show the sections, here is the fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/ywxbLswt/1/

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var option = 'About';
        var url = window.location.href;
        option = url.match(/option=(.*)/)[1];
        showDiv(option);
    });
    function showDiv(option) {
        $('.boxes').hide();
        $('#' + option).show();
    }
</script>

<ul>
    <li><a href="yourpage.html?option=About">About Us</a></li>
    <li><a href="yourpage.html?option=Link1">Link1</a></li>
</ul>


<div class="boxes" id="About">
    <h1>About Us</h1>
    <p>About content here</p>
</div>
<div class="boxes" id="Link1">
    <h1>Link1 Header</h1>
    <p>Link1 content here</p>
</div>
```

Try this.. hope this will help you out.