# Dynamically load content without refreshing the page

Tags: javascript, html, single-page-application

Can you dynamically load content inside a container by clicking on a link to avoid writing the same code for the header in multiple pages? I'm using Bootstrap.

Comment: oyur code is not really understandable and the question is not clear. try to post more complete code and exactly describe your problem

Comment: Why don't you make a seperate file with your header and include it on every page?

Comment: THis is wrong statement: `<div style hieght="2000px">`. It should look like: `<div style="height: 2000px;">`

Comment: similar to an iframe

Comment: you should use Single Page Application:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-page_application

Comment: @Banzay yeah noticed that just now sorry bout that.. 
hmm it would be a bit messy.. cause i plan to make the main page head fixed even when scrolling dow it just stays there.

Comment: Are your pages generated using PHP?

Comment: @OriPrice not sure how that works.. not really familiar with it.

Comment: @Fehniix nope completely static pages. not knowledgeable with php sadly

Comment: see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20958030/single-page-hide-show-section-based-on-current-position

Comment: You can use show and hide on different sections, onclick of link show that particular section and hide other sections. My recommendation is you can use some frameworks like angularJs if you are developing it from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for are [Single-page Applications](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-page_application).

For dynamically generated pages, the best approach to this situation is extending a main file containing information shared by multiple pages. By doing so, you overcome all the problems that come with a single-page application implementation.

For static pages, there are multiple ways to implement the functionalities of a  single-page application.

### AJAX

[AJAX](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/AJAX/Getting_Started) is the best and most used technique for this purpose. With AJAX, you can dynamically load inside an element the content of an external webpage. Using [jQuery](https://jquery.com/) makes this even easier:

```
<button id="link1">Link 1</button>
<div id="target"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
  jQuery(window).load(function() { // Run my code as soon as the page is ready
    jQuery('#link1').on('click', function() { // Bind closure to #link1's onClick event
      jQuery.get('myUrl', function(data) { // Perform AJAX GET request
        jQuery('#target').html(data); // If the request is successful, load the response inside the #target element
      });
    });
  });
</script>
```

### iframes

An alternative technique uses [iframes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe). The code used for this technique is almost completely analogous to the previous:

```
<button id="link1" src="link1Url">Link 1</button>
<iframe src="deafultPageUrl" id="target"></iframe>

<script type="text/javascript">
  jQuery(window).load(function() { // Run my code as soon as the page is ready
    jQuery('#link1').on('click', function(e) { // Bind closure to #link1's onClick event
      jQuery('#target').attr('src', jQuery(e.target).attr('src')); // Retrieve the src attribute from event.target, and update the iframe
    });
  });
</script>
```

### Show/Hide pre-loaded content

This technique is **not** recommended; the previous ones achieve *much better results*.
I decided to leave this here regardless because, in spite of inefficiency, it's practically a technique one could use to develop a single-page application.

It consists in *pre-loading* in your single page the content of all your other pages, and showing only the one the user requested. The latter would be forced, then, to download content he didn't request, which might never be even used. The additional content accounts for a bigger file size and consequentially slower loading time.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Fehniix, SPA is probably what you are after.  This is a great book does not rely on a framework (just jQuery): [https://www.amazon.com/Single-Page-Applications-end-end/dp/1617290750](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1617290750)

You also might add module loaders like Require.js as they are heavily used in SPAs (which can get complex quickly).